# Makefile can't see sh or bash cygwin bins using enviroment variable

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, cygwin

At my office we recently got a laptop replacement and now one of my colleagues and myself are having issues compiling our code.

One of our compilations tools requires Cygwin 32-bits version, I freshly installed one and my colleague copied and paste the one he had on its previous laptop.
The computer we got are 64-bits but the previously ones we had were also 64-bits.

Both of us are having the issue that makefile returns this error:

```
make: "C:\cygwin\bin"/sh: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:401: clean] Error 127
```

The way we're defining "C:\cygwin\bin" is using an environment variable CYGWIN_BINDIR and we call it like this in the makefile:

```
export CAT = "$(CYGWIN_BINDIR)"/cat
export TOUCH = "$(CYGWIN_BINDIR)"/touch
export SHELL = "$(CYGWIN_BINDIR)"/sh      <----Complaining part
export COPY = "$(CYGWIN_BINDIR)"/cp
export PERL = "$(CYGWIN_BINDIR)"/perl
```

I can see that the binary for sh exists in the given path, I know we're mixing backslashes with normal slash but I read that cygwin takes care of fixing this and we've been compiling like this for years.

If we modify from:

```
export SHELL = "$(CYGWIN_BINDIR)"/sh
```

To:

```
export SHELL = sh
```

Now the makefile is able to use the binary, it seems like only sh is the one complaining since all the other binaries like cat/touch/cp/etc... are being used by the makefile properly.

Any ideas of what are we missing here?

As I mentioned we've been using this for years. I don't know what are we missing in our cygwin set up.

Comment: If you are using a cygwin-compiled binary, like make, you cannot use windows-style pathnames with backslash directory separators.  Backslashes are special to POSIX programs (they are escapes).  You must use the POSIX-style path, at least `C:/cygwin/bin` and probably, for real cygwin, `/c/cygwin/bin`.

Comment: Seems like the double quotes are interpreted literally, can you remove them?

Comment: @MadScientist I would think the same but the other tools (rm, cp, cat, etc..) are being used by make without any issue. I want to think that it's working because make only invokes the tools and the tools execution is not linked to the make binary itself. Therefore if you provide a MS-DOS style, it will use that path to access the binary like for example C:\cygwin\bin\rm, but I'm not sure why it is not working with sh or bash (well maybe because those are used by make binary internally, I'll have to investigate that).

Comment: Make invokes the shell directly.  Other tools are given to the shell, in scripts, to run so make doesn't invoke them directly.

Comment: @AndreasLouv this worked and it makes sense, reading the make documentation it seems like it doesn't interprets quotes or double quotes and it's interpreting the path for the shell to use with double quotes included. Edit: A colleague shared her cygwin installation, which is a really old version, and using that one the code compiles... if I remove the double quotes then it doesn't compile and it seems like make is using the double quotes to interpret slashes since the error is because now the path is C:cygwinbin/sh maybe newer cygwin versions better comply with make spec.

Comment: @MadScientist yes this seems to be true, the issue is because of the double quotes as suggested by AndreasLouv, actually I see that cygwin is capable of use both type of slashes, even when they're combined, for example C:\cygwin\bin/bash. The error was to indicate the path of the SHELL to be "C:\cygwin\bin"/sh, the double quotes in the others variables work maybe because they're passed like this by make to the SHELL and the shell is capable of interprete double quotes but make doesn't.

Comment: @MadScientist: `/c/cygwin/bin` would not work in the default setup. The syntax is `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin`. However, undercygwin, `/` is usually mounted in a way that a lone `/usr/bin`  would do  as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that make (as it supposed to work) is handling double quotes as another character and is not expanding it as other interpreters do, like for example a shell interpreter.

Therefore make is trying to set the SHELL variable to the path `"C:\cygwin\bin"/sh` including double quotes and obviously that path doesn't exist.

Notice cygwin is capable of handle backslash and normal slash, even mixed.

This was fixed using a very old version of cygwin, where the double quotes are used to interpret backslashes, otherwise the path `"$(CYGWIN_BINDIR)"/s`h instead of being expanded to `C:\cygwin\bin/sh` is expanded to `C:cygwinbin/sh`.

I know we could have fixed our makefile to work with latest version of cygwin, but since this is a legacy project linked to other legacy tools we decided to use an older version of cygwin.